# How can I get the the recursion values to feed into the POWER FUNCTION?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

So I have this function and I have done much of the work on it so far. 
I am trying to feed the results from the addseries function into the power function to give me for example:

6^6 + 5^5 + 4^4 + 3^3 + 2^2 + 1+ 0 .. 
I am having a problem with getting it to work. Any suggestions?

```
def power(n):
    if(n<=0):
        return 0
else:
    return n**n


def addseries(num):
if(num == 0):
    return 0
    else:
        print(num)
        return sumseries(num - 1) + power(num)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would actually work if you simply fix the indentation and typos (`sumseries` should be `addseries`, for example):

```
def power(n):
    if(n<=0):
        return 0
    else:
        return n**n

def addseries(num):
    if(num == 0):
        return 0
    else:
        return addseries(num - 1) + power(num)
```

so that:

```
print(addseries(6))
```

would output:

```
50069
```

which you can verify in Python shell:

```
>>> 1**1 + 2**2 + 3**3 + 4**4 + 5**5 + 6**6
50069
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit simplified:

```
def addseries(num):
    if(num == 0):
        return 0
    else:
        print(num)
        return num**num + addseries(num - 1)
```

Comment: @NicoleFoster I know, where do you see `num^2`?

Comment: Wrong comment. Sorry. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring recursion:

```
n = 6
>>> sum(x ** x for x in range(n, 0, -1))
50069  
# 6 ** 6 + 5 ** 5 + 4 ** 4 + 3 ** 3 + 2 ** 2 + 1 ** 1 
# = 46656 + 3125 + 356 + 27 + 4 + 1 
# = 50069
```

Using recursion:

```
def power_function(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    return n ** n + power_function(n - 1)

>>> power_function(6)
50069
```

Comment: Yes with n = 6; it's 50070. REMEMBER IT"S (6^6) not (6*6)

Comment: OKay. Got it. Thanks